# Orchard 1.8 HQLQuery on Infoset

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm having trouble finding any examples on how to perform an HQLQuery against an infoset part.
I'm building a custom calendaring/events management module and need to query upcoming events.  I'm using strictly infoset (no EventPartRecord classes), however I can't seem to get the query right.

Each calendar can have multiple event categories to display and each event can also have multiple event categories to display.

The code below produces the error posted after the code:

```
    public IEnumerable<EventPart> GetUpcomingEventsForCalendar(CalendarPart calendar, 
        VersionOptions versionOptions, int count)
    {
        versionOptions = versionOptions ?? VersionOptions.Published;

        string[] ids = calendar.EventCategoryIds;

        var events = _contentManager.HqlQuery()
            .ForPart<EventPart>()
            .Where(alias => alias.ContentItem() ,a=>
                a.And(x => x.Ge("StartDate", DateTime.Today), y => y.InG("EventCategoryIds", ids)))
            .OrderBy(x => x.ContentItem(), order => order.Asc("StartDate"))
            .Slice(0, count);

        return events;
    }
```

Error:

```
Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator: 
ERROR - QueryException thrown from IContentPartDriver by
Web.Module.Events.Drivers.CalendarWidgetPartDriver
NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: StartDate of: 
Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemRecord [select distinct civ.Id as Id, 
ci.StartDate
from Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemVersionRecord as civ
join civ.ContentItemRecord as ci
where (ci.StartDate >= '2014-06-06 07:43:50' and ci.EventCategoryIds in
('2e1ab64c61434df78b7112a2142089bc') ) AND (civ.Published = True)
order by ci.StartDate]
```

Comment: I think it is not possible to query the infoset. This post explains the infoset http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/the-shift-how-orchard-painlessly-shifted-to-document-storage-and-how-it-ll-affect-you

Comment: Agreed, ended up having to use standard queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query on properties kept solely inside the `InfosetPart`. If you need to query on a certain properties of a part you need to have a backing record containing those - the classic way.